# Send HTML email to all users of a role in action not display .....help me please

Tags: emails

[image]

Send HTML email to all users of a role in action not display ;
only send HTML-email display
help me please.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! It's not really clear what are you asking; are you saying that you don't see the "Send HTML mail to all users of a role" in the options?

Answer (score 0):

That action comes from the [Mime Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) module, it's not one of Rules's defaults.

Once you've downloaded and installed the new module, just re-visit the Rules setup page and you'll find it in the list.